# JSON library exception in Python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

As the Python 2 API seems to be messed up - from file system functions I sometimes get unicode strings, sometimes standard strings - I am now attempting a transition from Python 2 to Python 3. But while doing so I run into problems regarding the `json` module.

I run a standard Ubuntu system with Python 3.4. When I try to use the JSON module I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sysmon.py", line 227, in <module>
    jsonCfgObj = json.load(json_file, 'utf-8', strict = False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 331, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

At first glance this seems to be a bug in the JSON module of Python 3. Something I can hardly believe because I don't do anything which would be out of the ordinary: I just read a very very simple JSON configuration file.

Do you have any ideas how to deal with this error?

Comment: What does your code look like? That would be helpful

Comment: See the stack trace: "jsonCfgObj = json.load(json_file, 'utf-8', strict = False)"
And if i remove the 'utf-8' everything works fine, as far as I can see. But then I get some other error right in the original code of the traceback module. I have much experience with other programming languages, so to me it seems to be a very strange behaviour not to get regular exceptions but errors within the original module code. Is this typical for python3? In python2 I never encountered such a thing. But that's something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `json.load` in Python 2 was `encoding`, however in Python 3 the second argument is `cls` and it must be `None` (the default) or `JSONDecoder` subclass. The signature of [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) is now

```
json.load(fp, cls=None, ...)
```

You need to remove `'utf-8'` from the list of arguments (pass it to the file opener instead).

---

OTOH [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) *still* has the `encoding` argument, but it "is ignored and deprecated".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. FYI: It definitively does not seem to be "ignored", regardless of what the specification says, because otherwise I would not have encountered that error. But thanx, that solved the problem!

Comment: @RegisMay it *is* ignored in `json.loads`, `json.load` simply does not allow the `encoding` argument. Also, if you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

[`json.load()` in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) does not accept binary files and therefore the 2nd parameter `encoding` is removed.

`'utf-8'` is interpreted as `cls` parameter here that is unrelated to the encoding that leads to the `TypeError` that you see. Drop `'utf-8'` from the `json.load()` call -- you should pass the encoding to the code that opens the file instead:

```
import json

with open('text.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```